# How to read a string/character from com port with java?

Tags: java, serial-port

I googled lot about reading from a com port but it seems very difficult work for me. I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wiki/jSSC_examples) but I don't know how to add jSSC library to my netbeans project.

Please help me by giving instructions to adding that library to my project or giving a simple code to read a string/character from a com port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add jSSC library in netbeans, right click on "Libraries" in your project and then "add JAR/Folder..." to select your file(s)

[image]

You can read with something like this :

```
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0");// For windows "COMX" (e.g : "COM1") should works
if (serialPort.openPort()) {
    serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_ODD);
    byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(1);// Read one byte
    String str = new String(buffer);
    serialPort.closePort();
}
```

Comment: I mean your library file(s). For jSSC add "jssc.jar" and then you can use it (import jssc.SerialPort;)

Comment: when i used System.out.println(str) It shows only one letter and stops. What changes do i have to do?

Comment: If you know how many bytes you will have replace "1" by your number in readBytes, otherwise you can use "getInputBufferBytesCount".

Comment: Thank u very much I can do what I wanted now.